# How can I understand when something is a variable or a value?

Tags: cmake

Not sure how to perfectly word this from the title, but I am new to CMake and slowly progressing through the online tutorial.

I am up to Step 4 and sometimes find it confusing when mixing passed values that in my eyes are strings, and thus in all programming languages I expect them to have quotation marks or some sort around them. However sometimes I create new targets with the same names. I will elaborate with an example. I reworded some things from the tutorial to make it a bit more clear for me to see what they actually do.

In the root CMakeLists.txt I have this file,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(My_Project VERSION 1.0)

add_library(tutorial_compiler_flags INTERFACE)

target_compile_features(tutorial_compiler_flags INTERFACE cxx_std_11)

option(USE_MYMATH "Use tutorial provided math implementation" TRUE)

configure_file(src/sqrt.h.in src/sqrt.h)



if(USE_MYMATH)

    add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)

    list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)

endif()

add_executable(compute_square_root src/sqrt.cxx)

target_link_libraries(compute_square_root PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS} tutorial_compiler_flags)

target_include_directories(compute_square_root PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/src")
```

Inside of `MathFunctions` I have

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)

target_include_directories(MathFunctions INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Here is where the confusion can come from. Notice that in

```
add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
```

MathFunctions is kind of treated as a string in my eyes, because it is now looking for the directory `current_location/MathFunctions`. However inside of of the MathFunctions CMakeLists.txt it now creates a target with the exact same spelling from the line "add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)", this is then immediately referenced afterwards from the "target_include_directories(MathFunctions, ...".

Here, target_include_directories is referring to the target MathFunctions we just created. Now, when we leave that CMakeLists.txt we now have another line "list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)". Now I some confusion, like, is this MathFunctions referring to the target we just made? Is it a string called "MathFunctions"? In the documentation for target_link_libraries it says that it has to be a target created by add_library so I assume it is referring to the previous add_library(MathFunctions ...) call. I find the scoping weird here too, since we are referring to something that was made from a child, inside a different call.

Do we have certain rules in CMake for this kind of behaviour? THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All command parameters are treated as strings in cmake. Parameters are separated by whitespace unless quoted. The exact effect of a parameter depends on the command.

The following commands have the same effect:

```
add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
add_subdirectory("MathFunctions")
```

In the case of `add_library` the first parameter is treated as the target name. CMake internally keeps track of targets and stores several pieces of information for them. The target name `MathFunctions` is entirely unrelated to the name of the subdirectory added via `add_subdirectory`; you could rename the directory to `FooBar` and use `add_subdirectory(FooBar)` and nothing would change.

There are several commands you pass the target name to to modify the properties of the cmake target as well as commands that treat the name of cmake targets specially e.g.:

- `target_include_directories`: the target to modify the `[INTERFACE_]INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property for is passed
- `target_link_directories`: the target to modify the `[INTERFACE_]LINK_DIRECTORIES` property for is passed
- `set_target_properties`: One or more targets to set properties for are passed
- `target_link_libraries`: The cmake target linked to is passed. Furthermore cmake library targets may be specified as libraries to be linked to the target.
- `add_test`: If you use the name of a cmake target in the `COMMAND` part, the test logic uses the path to the target instead.
- ...

As for scope:

Variable values you write are actually set for the current scope only, but reading variables cmake looks into ancestor scopes, unless a variable is found in the current scope. CMake targets are visible in the whole cmake project though from the point of the parsing of the command creating the target(`add_library`, `add_executable`, `add_custom_target`): cmake targets are "global objects". (Exceptions exist for imported libs and alias targets, but that's probably nothing relevant to you right now.)

Comment: Thanks. I guess some of my confusion was thinking of this like a typical programming language where I was thinking of it as something like `MathFunctions = add_library(MathFunctions, ...)` so typing `MathFunctions` elsewhere, I was not sure if it was referring to a string or the target, but you're saying that it does not do this and instead adds a new target to a stack that can later be referenced by other methods such as `target_include_directories(MathFunctions, ...)` where it will look on the target stack for something called "MathFunctions".

Comment: Why is it that my parent can see the creation of the target `MathFunctions` when calling it through `add_subdirectory(Mathfunctions, ...)` but if I add a `set(MyString "Some Text")` inside `MathFunctions: CMakeLists.txt` I cannot get a correct print value using `message(STATUS "${MyString}")` after the call to `add_subdirectory(MathFunctions, ...)`?